# Generate custom java code like lombok at compile time

Tags: java, spring, jvm, classloader, lombok

I want create an annotation to append a new variable to annotated class at compile time like the below, it accepts variable name and variable type

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface AddNewVariable {
    String fieldName();
    Class<?> fieldType();
}
```

I tried to use AbstractProcessor to generate the code but I found that the limitation of the annotation processing API — it can only be used to generate new files, not to change existing ones.

> I want change in the exist class like Lombok at compile time

**
I develop Spring Application and I use hibernate ORM, I have a generic columns like (is_Active, is_deleted, created_by, create_on, etc.) but I don't want all entities inherit them from mapped super class, because in some cases, One class want only is_active and is_deleted or any combination of them. So I suggest to make it by annotation, if class want generic columns, it should add annotation with the variables name and types

**

Example

I want write the below

```
@AddNewVariable("isActive", Boolean.class)
Class User {
int id;
String fullName;
int age;
}
```

My expectation is the below int the target folder

```
Class User {
int id;
String fullName;
int age;
boolean isActive;
}
```

Comment: "it can only be used to generate new files" and that's exactly what you want to do here. You want to generate a new file with the same contents as the existing file, except for `<insert changes here>`.

Comment: I want change in the same class file, and I know that limitation of Abstract processor that it can only be used to generate new files, not to change existing ones

Comment: It's a shame that Java does not support mix-ins, as this would be a good use case. Sometimes interfaces with default methods can be used to achieve it, but in this case the default method would need state, and that's something that's still not possible with interfaces.

Comment: I don’t see the point of adding an annotation like `@AddNewVariable("isActive", Boolean.class)` to a class instead of inserting `boolean isActive;` in the first place. Remembers me on the developer who wrote `@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PACKAGE)` instead of just `MyClass(){}`

Comment: Hello @Holger I want make something like Lombok

Comment: As an end in itself?